# IntelliJ: Jump to source of calling method

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Can I using debugger in IntelliJ check from where was called method (source call) ?

For example I have method `public Object getSomething(int i)` and I toggle breakpoint at this method. Debugger stoped and there is my question - Can I check from where was called this method ?

I am using OS X system on MacBook.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to jump to the callers of the method.

(<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> on MAC)

<s>Edit: I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) will be helpful, this will take you straight to the caller of the function.</s>

Edit2: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) pulls up the Debugger window where you can see all the previous calls made. There you can choose the caller of your method in question.

Comment: Yea I know this but I work on big project and there are many callers. I want find current caller when debugger stops on breakpoint. Any idea ?

Comment: Yeah gimmi a sec to test a few theories ;)

Comment: Weird it jumps to specific caller for me. You are in debug mode right?

Comment: Yes. Command+F7 doesn't show me nothing and Alt + F7 show me all callers. When using Command + F7 it return me info `Not find usages of method in tableModel.java`

Comment: I find probably solution: Command + 5 show Debug window, there is `Frames` overlap and it show last las called methods ;)

Comment: YES ofcourse! How could I be so dumb, I actually saw that in my Intellij and just didn't process lol good work

Comment: Thanks for Yours answers, It was helpful ! :)

Comment: sorry sir， _**1.**_    If　there are multiple callers,  which caller will we jump to?                _**2.**_ For the edit2 answer, I didn't see any debugging window after pressing **`Command + 5`**,    I tried to search keymap, the shortcut **`Command + 5`** doesn't exist