# jump to the caller methods from a breakpoint in IntelliJ using Ubuntu/linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

How can I jump to the caller methods from a breakpoint in IntelliJ using Ubuntu/linux? The Mac keystrokes does not work on ubuntu! Mac keystrokes can be found here [IntelliJ: Jump to source of calling method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573587/intellij-jump-to-source-of-calling-method)

Thank you for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

The action is called **Show Usages**. Search the Keymap to see what hotkey is used on your system (probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>).

But what you need is just open the Debugger tool window and use the **Frames** view to jump from.